# Want to manually send SYN ACK packets to establish TCP connection (in PHP if possible)

Tags: php, tcp

How can I send my own SYN and ACK packets to a server in php. I do not want the system to do anything, I would like to create my own packets, and send them myself to establish the TCP connection. Can this be done in php, or do I have to use C++ for this, or maybe python, or bash (shell script), which ever is easiest. And can some one direct me to a good place to learn what the contents of a SYN and ACK packet is exactly. I know a SYN packet has the IP address, and other details on where to send the server's ACK reply to.

Thanks,

macintosh264

Comment: If you need to talk to a server which has no corresponding library functions in PHP, you can use [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php). If you actually need to manually craft individual packets, you won't find anything in the core language and you'll probably have to use another language or an extension. Why do you need to send these packets manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a raw network library for PHP.  A quick search turned up [prnl](http://code.google.com/p/prnl/).  Support is likely to be uneven across operating systems, though; so-called "raw sockets" are sometimes considered to be sensitive items.

Comment: +1: Nice find.  I took a look at [the source](http://code.google.com/p/prnl/source/browse/trunk/lib/network/raw.network.class.php), and it seems to be built on top of [`socket_create()`](http://php.net/socket-create) with `SOCK_RAW`.