# PHP force close (kill) a connection

Tags: php, sockets, curl, kill

I've ran some tests with sockets (using `fsockopen()` and `stream_socket_client()`) and cURL to force closing a connection (TCP/HTTP). However, no luck.

Whether I use a 1ms timeout (on cURL the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS option requires a minimal of 1s anyway) or quit a connection immediately after opening it with blocking disabled, it still works flawless.

I haven't tried forking (`pcntl_fork()`) my script, but my server doesn't support it anyway.

Is there any other way to kill a connection in PHP? It's quite disappointing you can't in PHP while you can in C# :(

---

Edit: Let me clarify my question as it might be somewhat confusing:

I want to see if PHP allows developers to send a SYN. That's all. One, single, SYN packet using PHP's native functions.

Comment: Isn't that what `fclose()`, `socket_close()`, and `curl_close()` are for?

Comment: @MetalFrog no, at that point the SYN, SYN-ACK and ACK are already sent. That's not a force close or kill, that's closing a connection normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems related to another Stack Overflow question about sending raw, low level data via PHP: [Want to manually send SYN ACK packets to establish TCP connection (in PHP if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989913/want-to-manually-send-syn-ack-packets-to-establish-tcp-connection-in-php-if-pos)

The library mentioned in the answer was [prnl](http://code.google.com/p/prnl/) which does the job but I haven't played with too  heavily just yet. From the description:

> PRNL is a PHP library aimed at the execution of low level networking tasks. In this first release we started with the possibility of transmitting and receiving raw IP packets. With PRNL you are able to create and transmit custom IP packets with matching TCP and UDP packets.

If you're using PHP via Apache then you're going to find that Apache has already established a connection before your PHP has a chance to run. I'm not sure at this point if you have the ability to intervene in the handshake at that point.

If this isn't what you're looking for please update the question and I'll see what I can find to get you what you're looking for.

Comment: In this case, PHP has nothing to do with Apache. Besides, PRNL only runs from command line so has nothing to do with web applications. Finally, you don't have sufficient access to create those sockets on Mac or Windows. If you're lucky you can on Linux...

Comment: You didn't say if you were trying this in an app or just as proof of concept. As for PRNL you should be able to call/instantiate its objects from your code as needed and do more than just command line access. What server environment are you running on?

Comment: OSX 10.6.8 and me being lazy installed an MAMP server. It seems to be a perfect solution and I'm definitely willing to use it, but I keep getting this error: `Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted`. Could it be MAMP? That would be silly.. Many thanks for your support so far and in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to `socket_close`?

Or `exit()` the script if should close connection instantly.

Comment: I've tried both and both still closed the connection normally.